# Python Table Widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently working on my optimization software project using python. I want my user can input the data in the table. But, also the user can choose how many rows and column they need. Is there's another solution out there instead of tktable or tkinter table widget?

Comment: You may want to research ttk.treeview.

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Comment: By the way, I still need to implement function on the table and the value inside table should be editable

Comment: Have you considered simply using a grid of entry widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option one:**

use wxgrid from wxpython. It's an excel like grid writen in c++ that can be used in python, so (it's by nature) faster than the second option. And supports larger data sets.

Iv'e installed it by puting this in CMD (windows):

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

But if you have other versions of python 2 alongside python 3, you need to put "pip3" instead of "pip" to point to your python 3.X installation if its the case.

here's an example:

[Example](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-an-introduction-to-grids/)

**Option2:**

Use pandastable (only for python 3.x). It is entirely written in python, so may be just a little more slow by nature, although uses numpy (that is written in C++ ). In addition, supported data set size is limited by RAM.

you need to install all dependencies (numpy, matplotlib, numexpr, pandas) before install:

```
pip install pandastable
```

if you have other versions of Pyton 2, you need to put "pip3".

for more information visit :
[install pandastable](http://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html#installation)

Here is an example of how it looks like:
[example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Hcg.jpg)